# Cypress AzureAD login always redirects outside the cypress window

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-active-directory, cypress, msal.js

I am trying to implement the Azure AD login automation using Cypress using login post call and setting the local session storage as mentioned in the github https://github.com/juunas11/AzureAdUiTestAutomation. But even after setting all the local and session storage, once I run the tests, it keeps navigating to the microsoft authentication page and also its redirected outside the cypress window. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated since I am stuck on this and unable to proceed forward with the automation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQerI.png)

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import { decode, JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import authSettings from './authsettings.json';

const {
    authority, //"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id"
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    apiScopes,
    username,
    password,
    apiScopesEntity,
    targetScopes,
} = authSettings;// storing all the above details in a separate file (authSettings.js)

const environment = 'login.windows.net';

const buildAccountEntity = (
    homeAccountId,
    realm,
    localAccountId,
    username,
    name
) => {
    return {
        authorityType: 'MSSTS',
        clientInfo: 'to enter client-info',
        homeAccountId,
        environment,
        realm,
        localAccountId,
        username,
        name,
    };
};

const buildIdTokenEntity = (homeAccountId, idToken, realm) => {
    return {
        credentialType: 'IdToken',
        homeAccountId,
        environment,
        clientId,
        secret: idToken,
        realm,
    };
};

const buildAccessTokenEntity = (
    homeAccountId,
    accessToken,
    expiresIn,
    extExpiresIn,
    realm
) => {
    const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    return {
        homeAccountId,
        credentialType: 'AccessToken',
        secret: accessToken,
        cachedAt: now.toString(),
        expiresOn: (now + expiresIn).toString(),
        extendedExpiresOn: (now + extExpiresIn).toString(),
        environment,
        clientId,
        realm,
        target: targetScopes,
        tokenType: 'Bearer',
    };
};

const buildProfileEmailEntity = (
    homeAccountId,
    accessToken,
    expiresIn,
    extExpiresIn,
    realm
) => {
    const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    return {
        homeAccountId,
        credentialType: 'AccessToken',
        secret: accessToken,
        cachedAt: now.toString(),
        expiresOn: (now + expiresIn).toString(),
        extendedExpiresOn: (now + extExpiresIn).toString(),
        environment,
        clientId,
        realm,
        target: 'openid profile email',
        tokenType: 'Bearer',
    };
};

const buildRefreshTokenEntity = (
    homeAccountId,
    accessToken,
) => {
    return {
        homeAccountId,
        credentialType: 'RefreshToken',
        secret: accessToken,
        environment,
        clientId,
    };
};

const injectTokens = (tokenResponse) => {
    const idToken = decode(tokenResponse.access_token);
    const localAccountId = idToken.oid || idToken.sid;
    const realm = idToken.tid;
    const homeAccountId = `${localAccountId}.${realm}`;
    const username = idToken.unique_name;
    const name = idToken.name;

    const accountKey = `${homeAccountId}-${environment}-${realm}`;
    const accountEntity = buildAccountEntity(
        homeAccountId,
        realm,
        localAccountId,
        username,
        name
    );

    const idTokenKey = `${homeAccountId}-${environment}-idtoken-${clientId}-${realm}---`;
    const idTokenEntity = buildIdTokenEntity(
        homeAccountId,
        tokenResponse.access_token,
        realm
    );

    const accessTokenKey = `${homeAccountId}-${environment}-accesstoken-${clientId}-${realm}-${apiScopesEntity}--`;
    const accessTokenEntity = buildAccessTokenEntity(
        homeAccountId,
        tokenResponse.access_token,
        tokenResponse.expires_in,
        tokenResponse.ext_expires_in,
        realm
    );

    const profileEmailKey = `${homeAccountId}-${environment}-accesstoken-${clientId}-${realm}-openid profile email`;
    const profileEmailEntity = buildProfileEmailEntity(
        homeAccountId,
        tokenResponse.access_token,
        tokenResponse.expires_in,
        tokenResponse.ext_expires_in,
        realm
    );

    const refreshTokenKey = `${homeAccountId}-${environment}-refreshtoken-${clientId}--`;
    const refreshTokenEntity = buildRefreshTokenEntity(homeAccountId,
        tokenResponse.access_token);

    cy.window().then(win => {
        win.sessionStorage.clear();
        win.localStorage.clear();

        win.sessionStorage.setItem(accountKey, JSON.stringify(accountEntity));
        win.sessionStorage.setItem(idTokenKey, JSON.stringify(idTokenEntity));
        win.sessionStorage.setItem(accessTokenKey, JSON.stringify(accessTokenEntity));
        win.sessionStorage.setItem(profileEmailKey, JSON.stringify(profileEmailEntity));
        win.sessionStorage.setItem(refreshTokenKey, JSON.stringify(refreshTokenEntity));

        win.localStorage.setItem(accountKey, JSON.stringify(accountEntity));
        win.localStorage.setItem(idTokenKey, JSON.stringify(idTokenEntity));
        win.localStorage.setItem(accessTokenKey, JSON.stringify(accessTokenEntity));
        win.localStorage.setItem(profileEmailKey, JSON.stringify(profileEmailEntity));
        win.localStorage.setItem(refreshTokenKey, JSON.stringify(refreshTokenEntity));

    })
    
};

export const login = () => {
    let tokenResponse = null;
    cy.request({
            url: authority + '/oauth2/v2.0/token',
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                grant_type: 'password',
                client_id: clientId,
                client_secret: clientSecret,
                scope: apiScopes,
                username: username,
                password: password,
            },
            form: true,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            injectTokens(response.body);
            tokenResponse = response.body.access_token;
        })
        .reload()
        .then(() => {
            return tokenResponse;
        });
};
```

Comment: @juunas I have been trying to implement how you have done it. But I am not able to achieve it. Need some support on this.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and i realized why this is happening and the cause of the redirection is that the data that you saved in localstorage is not exactly what the msal in the front end or the library you are using to log in, are expecting. For this reason you are getting redirected.

**follow this steps to solve that problem**

**1-** You need to stop the redirection to stop visiting the site with cy.visit("/") commenting it; after the request to microsoft to avoid be redirected and maintain the test window to see the localstorage values and console.logs you are going to add to see the decoded token response, something like that console.log('idToken', idToken);

**2-** Pay attention to the tokenResponse when you are going to inyect the token in localstorage. In my case the response was in an access_token variable instead of id_token.

**3-** Go to localstorage of the application(the real front end, not the one that is being testing by cypress) and check for all items in localstorage and see the differences between the objects you have, dont worry about the key of the values, only check its values.

**4-** Try to fill the missing fields to looks like the localstorage values that are in the front end app(not the cypress browser window) and run the test again. you can take a look at the console.log previous value, and maybe more data of the token response. For me worked with a few modifications in the place where you inyect the token:

```
console.log('token response', tokenResponse);
const idToken = decode(tokenResponse.access_token);
console.log('idToken', idToken);
const localAccountId = idToken.oid || idToken.sid;
// const realm = idToken?.tid;
const realm = 'my-sing-up-sing-in-policy';
// const homeAccountId = `${localAccountId}.${realm}`;
const homeAccountId = `${localAccountId}-${realm}.a-string-that-i-took-from-the-front-end-local-storage`;
// const username = idToken.preferred_username;
const username = idToken.emails[0];
```

as you can see i had missing data in the response and i needed to complemented it with data matching the real app localstorage data and the result in the localstorage cypress browser window. You need to pay attention to the data is missing. In my example i did a few modifications and worked, but maybe your case is different.